# Environment.Clone Steals Startup Time

Tags: performance, build, environment, scons

We are as good as done converting our large GNU Make build system to SCons.

Everthing works nicely except that we have 7 seconds of startup time spent in `Environment.Clone()`. We are using `Clone()` because of its nice functional style of not modifying existing global state.

Has anybody come up with a way to ***not*** copy 99 percent of the `Environment` data never gets changed in the `Clone` anyway?

Would removing non-used keys in its dictionary improve `Clone()` time?

Comment: How large is the project? How many source files are there?

Comment: Project consists of about 150 of separate components (CIs) each with its own SConscript and env.Clone(). I revised the number to 7 secs after correcting a bug.

Comment: Around 2-3 thousand source files in C, C++, Fortran and Ada.

Comment: And what is the overall build time as compared to the previous make system? You can execute the following to see get an overview of the time: scons --debug=time ...

Comment: The build time is ok. Our largest problem is our slow NFS solution and that we most our code is in Ada. I have heavily modified the scons-ada builder to work completely now. We are using all the bells and whistels of Ada generics sub-packages etc. What remains to optimize is the startup time for small (partial builds). Therefore the question.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you could consider dividing your build into several smaller builds, each controlled by its seperate SConstruct build script, while maintaining the current SConstruct for the complete build.  I could imagine that a developer changing the c++ code would only need to build the complete project once to get the non-c++ dependencies. And then while working on the c++ feature, he/she would only need to build the c++. Likewise for ada and fortran.

For example, assuming you have something similar to the following dir structure:

```
root_dir
|
+--- src_ada
|
+--- src_cpp
|
+--- src_fortran
```

You could have a root level SConstruct for each type of build, as follows:

```
SConstruct             # performs a complete build
SConstruct.ada         # builds just the ada
SConstruct.cpp         # builds just the cpp
SConstruct.fortran     # builds just the fortran
```

If these SConstruct scripts are correctly created, then the subsidiary SConscript build scripts probably wouldnt need to be modified.

You could even take this one step further by creating a build wrapper script that could take the following command line arguments:

```
build [complete (default arg) | ada | cpp | fortran]
```

And internally, the script would call scons with the appropriate SConstruct, which could be one of the following:

```
scons -f SConstruct
scons -f SConstruct.ada
scons -f SConstruct.cpp
scons -f SConstruct.fortran
```

Notice the options `-f file, --file=file, --makefile=file, --sconstruct=file` all do the same: let you specify which SConstruct to use for the build, as explained in the [SCons man pages](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to have several different Environment objects that would be passed to the different subsidiary SConscript build scripts. You could have one that has general build settings applicable to all subsidiary SConscript scripts that would not need to be cloned, and then different Environment objects for the different programming languages, that would selectively be passed to subsidiary SConscript scripts, depending on the needs therein. These more specific Environment objects would probably need to be cloned.

Separating the Environment objects like this should speed-up the cloning, as only the needed information for a particular subsidiary SConscript script would be cloned.